# In Mercurial what's the difference between hg graft and hg rebase

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I know [Rebase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) is a (bundled) extension, while [Graft](http://selenic.com/hg/help/graft) is a core feature (that replaced the [Transplant](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TransplantExtension) (bundled) extension).

**`graft`** is documented as:

> copy changes from other branches onto the current branch
>
> This command uses Mercurial's merge logic to copy individual changes from other branches without merging branches in the history graph. This is sometimes known as 'backporting' or 'cherry-picking'.

**`rebase`** is documented as:

> Rebase allows moving commits around in Mercurial's history (using a series of internal merges). This has many uses:
>
> - moving changesets between branches
> - "linearizing" history
> - reordering changesets
> - collapsing multiple changes into one changeset

Both seem to use merging to move or copy changesets between branches.

Graft copies. Rebase moves. But `rebase --keep` copies.

So often it seems I can accomplish my goal of copying a changeset either way.
Does it matter which one I use? When should I prefer one over the other?

E.g. should graft only be used when copying to a different *named* branch? Or only when there's just a single changeset?

---

Edit: Could it be that rebase is a potentially unsafe superset of graft, but can only be used with `draft` changesets during development for editing local history, while graft is a safe subset of rebase that can be used with `public` changesets during maintenance for backporting?

Comment: Note that my main question is not necessarily to get a list of all the minor technical differences, but to find a rule / rationale to decide between them **when either seem to work**. Or should I just use whichever seems more convenient?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`hg graft` allows "cherry-picking," as you noted in your question. For example, you can run `hg graft -D "2085::2093 and not 2091"` to copy only *some* changes from another revision. By comparison, `hg rebase` (with or without `--keep`) will grab whatever changeset you specify and *all* of its decendant changes.

Also, `rebase` allows you to collapse changesets (with `--collapse`). As far as I can tell, `graft` does not.

One more difference I have noticed: `hg graft --edit 123` lets you graft revision 123 to the working directory and edit the commit message. I can't find an `hg rebase` equivalent. I should point out, though, that `hg histedit` also allows for editing the commit message while rebasing.

There are probably other differences that I am not thinking of. SO community: feel free to point those out in the comments, and I will happily revise this answer to make it more complete.

See [the `graft` documentation](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/graft) and [the Rebase Extension documentation](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't `hg rebase --rev "2085::2093 and not 2091"` also allow "cherrypicking"?

Comment: Graft will copy _and_ refer back to the original changeset, which is very useful in cherry-picking.
You should be able to see this using 'hg log --debug'.

Comment: @Mathiasdm: Do you mean the `graft_source`? Doesn't rebase have the same thing with `rebase_source`?

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, I didn't know rebase_source existed :-) Hm, in that case, I don't think there's much difference between the rebase you suggest versus graft.

Comment: @Peter Maybe. I can't find anything in the docs about doing that kind of selective rebasing. I just tested it with a sample repository and it seemed to turn out alright, although I got a couple of unfamiliar complaints from hg along the way. Note, though, that it definitely only works with `hg rebase --keep` -- you can't do a selective rebase without `--keep`, or hg will flip out.

Comment: `hg rebase` doesn't allow to "cherry-pick" changesets that are an ancestor of the destination, even with `--keep`, but `hg graft` does with `--force`. This may be useful e.g. when a changeset has been applied earlier and later been reverted, and you want to apply it again now.