# Created a named branch from the wrong parent

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am stuck in a scenario in which I have created a branch on Mercurial Workbench from a wrong parent branch. In other words I had to create a feature branch from parent : xxx and I have created it from parent : yyy.

Please note that I have also committed the changes, Is there any way I can either redirect my feature branch to xxx or I can delete the branch and re-create it with the same name (please note that having the same name is important) but this time I can create it from xxx.

I have exported the patches of my commits so after creating a branch even if my commits are lost I can import the patches again.

Answer (score 3):

If you needed to change the branch *name* you would want `hg graft` (see [Graft vs. Transplant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8009632/1256452)).  But since you *don't* want to change the name, you only want to redo the *base* of the commits, you want `hg rebase`.

See [Hg: How to do a rebase like git's rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2672351/1256452) and also [In Mercurial what's the difference between hg graft and hg rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29539866/1256452).  Note that rebase is an extension, but is a bundled one: you merely need to enable it.